# Wagtail Admin: How to Add ReadOnlyBlocks to show snippets fields values in a StructBlock

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I have a Snippet model(SampleSnippet) with fields field_a, field_b, and field_c. And I am using it in a StructBlock like:

```
class SampleBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    service_snippet = SnippetChooserBlock(SampleSnippet)
    ...
```

Now I want to show some of the `SampleSnippet` fields(field_a and field_b) in `SampleBlock` after saving the SampleBlock for the first time(after saving the snippet) on the wagtail admin site. How can I achieve this? I looked around a lot but couldn't find a similar issue.

If it were a model/snippet, I could have used property with ReadOnlyPanel but in the case of a StructBlock, I am stuck and not getting any ideas. If anybody knows any way to achieve this, please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be quite difficult, since in current Wagtail versions (>=2.13) the StreamField editing UI is populated client-side in Javascript - as such, there are some extra steps to make the necessary data available to the client-side code, and the standard Django form / template mechanisms won't be available.

A simple workaround, if the fields aren't too long, would be to define the snippet's `__str__` method to include the desired data - this will then display any time the snippet is shown in the admin.

For a full solution, I'd suggest this approach:

- Set up a custom `form_template` for your StructBlock as detailed in [Custom editing interfaces for StructBlock](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/streamfield_blocks.html#custom-editing-interfaces-for-structblock), with placeholder `<div>` elements to contain your additional data.
- Override the StructBlock's [`get_form_state`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/ef2fa2e3944a7844b08aa070552f5046d5433a7f/wagtail/core/blocks/struct_block.py#L214) so that the returned dict (which will be used to populate the form template on the client side) includes your additional fields - something like:

  ```
  def get_form_state(self, value):
      data = super().get_form_state(value)
      data['field_a'] = value['service_snippet'].field_a
      data['field_b'] = value['service_snippet'].field_b
      return data
  ```
- Set up a custom JS adapter following the steps in [Additional JavaScript on StructBlock forms](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/streamfield_blocks.html#additional-javascript-on-structblock-forms). In the final `render` method, the data you returned from `get_form_state` will be available as `initialState`, and you can use this to populate the placeholder `<div>`s in the template.

Comment: I edited the question, I forgot to mention the admin part there. I want to show the read only fields in wagtail admin part with the `SampleBlock`, not in the client side form.

Comment: Yes, that's how I understood it. My answer is about how to get the additional data showing in the Wagtail admin.

Comment: Ahh, I get it. I misread `form_template` to `template`. It works but instead of overriding the `get_form_state`, I needed to override the `get_form_context`. Js adapter part also looks optional, because we have added the fields in context and can adjust the template as per our requirement.

Comment: Sounds like you're probably on Wagtail 2.12 or earlier. In 2.13 and above, the form template is only rendered with an empty value, and you'll need the JS code to populate it with the correct data.